# Stepping through the GUI in Java

Tags: java, debugging, swing, user-interface

We are working on a Java program with a GUI and we are looking for a tool that shows us which parts of code are executed as we click on the buttons in the GUI. Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eclipse with debug mode can do that, you just need to put break points in your listeners and click on the buttons.

It works out of the box with eclipse... a simple run Debug and it's done.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong but I think when there are multiple threads running this does not work that well. The program gets stuck at the break point becoming unresponsive and the debugger does not focus to the break point.

Comment: That is not correct I use eclipse debug with several threads and it sometimes loose track of the current thread, but you only have to select it from the thread list and the debug is online again.

Comment: Sorry, this is simply not useful in an application with 30+ threads. If I already know where to look, I don't need a tool to find it.

Comment: That is why I switched to intelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use [BlueJ](https://www.bluej.org/download/download.html) debugger:

http://www.stfrank.com/debug-21.png

Comment: Never heard of it. Neat.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use print statements. If you require more sophistication, either use an IDE (e.g. Eclipse, NetBeans, and etc.) in debug mode, or some logging mechanism (e.g. log4j).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Swing Explorer](http://www.swingexplorer.com/)

Comment: seems very powerful swing debugger +1

Comment: but doesn't works with some Custom L&F and refuse to display some COntainers from SwingX libraries

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, please refer to [this](https://github.com/robotframework/SwingLibrary).